# Edit multiple saved records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to develop a simple exercise log app, and I'm stuck (again). A user selects a category, and a specific workout, and I return a list of exercises belonging to that workout.

An effort is a user specific instance of an exercise.

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :efforts
end

class Effort < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exercise
end
```

I'm retrieving the list of exercises in the efforts controller

```
class EffortsController < ApplicationController
  def log_workout
    @exercises = Exercise.where("category_id = ? AND workout_id = ?", params[:exercise][:category_id], params[:exercise][:workout_id])
    @effort = Effort.new
  end
end
```

The user logs their workout by using the following form

```
<%= form_tag save_workout_path, method: :put do %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Exercise</th>
    <th>Sets</th>
    <th>Reps</th>
  </tr>
  <% @exercises.each do |exercise| %>
  <%= fields_for "efforts[]", @effort do |f| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= exercise.name %></td>
      <td><%= f.number_field :sets %></td>
      <td><%= f.number_field :reps %></td>
      <%= f.hidden_field :exercise_id, :value => exercise.id %>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
<%= submit_tag "Log it" %>
<% end %>

class EffortsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    params[:efforts].each do |values|
      if current_user.efforts.create(values)
        flash[:notice] = 'Efforts were successfully saved.'
      else
        render action: 'new'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How right this is, I'm not sure, but it works. My problem now is trying to retrieve saved 'efforts' and allowing them to be modified through the same form. (Letting the user edit their workout log). Would appreciate any guidance/help

Comment: How do you link the `Effort` to the `Exercise` model in your Controller? Because `Effort.new` will not set the correct ids to the `Exercise` it belongs to. You should use `@exercise.efforts.build`. `build()` will 'build' an `Effort` for you where the foreign keys are already set correctly to that `Exercise`.

Comment: I have to admit that I don't get this. I think I understand the build method but the implementation stumps me. The code that I'm using to create the effort records is above. I'm creating them field by field and setting the Exercise id foreign key from the params hash where I've passed it as a hidden field. Am I right in thinking that to use the build method, the foreign key should be available through the routing? In that case I'm handling the routing incorrectly